# How to find the index of a number in two Dimension Array that it is the higher in row and the lower in a column in the same time

Tags: java

I got this question as a homework and a i could find the number but i could not 
find the index and my code was disaster many loops many variables how can i find the index of the number if the number is repeated in the array and how to Shortcut the code

---

public class Homework {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
int [][] Array_numbers={{ 1 , 3 , 32},
                        { 4 , 5 , 6 },
                        { 7 , 8 , 9 }};
int[] Sum_row=new int[Array_numbers.length];
int[] Sum_column=new int[Array_numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < Array_numbers.length; i++) {

    int First_column=Array_numbers[i][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < Array_numbers[i].length; j++) {

        if (Array_numbers[i][j]>First_column){
            First_column=Array_numbers[i][j];}

        Sum_row[i]=First_column;}



    int First_row=Array_numbers[0][i];
for (int k = 0; k < Array_numbers[i].length; k++) {
    if(Array_numbers[k][i]<=First_row){
        First_row=Array_numbers[k][i];
        Sum_column[i]=First_row;}}}



int The_number = 0;
for (int s = 0; s < Sum_column.length; s++) {
    for (int p = 0; p < Sum_row.length; p++) {
        if(Sum_column[s]==Sum_row[p]){
            The_number=Sum_column[s];
            System.out.println(Sum_column[s]);}}}



for (int loop = 0; loop < Array_numbers.length; loop++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < Array_numbers[loop].length; k++) {
        if (Array_numbers[loop][k]==The_number){
            System.out.println(loop+","+k);}
```

}}}}

Comment: And please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @GhostCat i hope now you can read it

Comment: I'm not really clear on the stated goal.  Do you have an example of what output you expect given your two-dimension array?

Comment: @Makoto to print the index of  a number that is the greatest in the row and in the same time the same number is the smallest number in column in my example the output is 1,2 because 6 is greater than 4 and five and smaller than 9 and 32 i am facing a problem when i print the index if i got another 6 the output will be tow indexes the correct one and the wrong one

Comment: Naming is better, but still not following the Java naming conventions. Variables go camelCase, and you only use the _ character for constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main concept to make this "disaster" a better-structured application is to break it down into manageable sub-tasks like

- Is the element at r,c the highest one in its row?
- Is the element at r,c the lowest one in its column?

A solution along this pattern could be like

```
private static boolean isHighestInItsRow(int[][] array, int row, int col) {
    // I'll leave that to you
}

private static boolean isLowestInItsColumn(int[][] array, int row, int col) {
    // I'll leave that to you
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] array = {
        { 1 , 3 , 32},
        { 4 , 5 , 6 },
        { 7 , 8 , 9 }
    };

    for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++) {
            if (isHighestInItsRow(array, r, c) && isLowestInItsColumn(array, r, c)) {
                System.out.println("Solution is row " + r + " / column " + c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't the `main` method look straightforward now? It simply tries every row/column combination and checks if it fulfills the two conditions stated in your task.

As it's your homework, I left out how to write the methods `isHighestInItsRow` and `isLowestInItsColumn`. But I'm sure you'll solve that.

**Remarks:**

My suggestion surely isn't the most efficient algorithm, but in software engineering code readability comes first, and efficiency only when you experience problems there.

In production code, I'd typically not place the `System.out.println()` calls into the method doing the computation, but instead have the computation collect its results into a `List` or something similar, and print that `List` later on in another method.